# How to add options while in text box

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA but trying to learn. This is what I essentially want it to do but have no idea how to define what I want or where to look (will have comments with '')

```vb
Dim AnswerYes As String
 Dim AnswerNo As String

 AnswerYes = MsgBox("Is there already a preset?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "User Repsonse")
      If AnswerYes = vbYes Then
         MsgBox ("Select desired preset") ''can choose from saved presets ie Matt1, Matt2, etc
      If AnswerNo = vbNo Then
         MsgBox ("Would you like to make a preset?")
             IfYes
                MsgBox ("Create a name for preset") ''name would create a new preset ie Matt3
                   MsgBox ("Enter desired values") ''values would be saved so they could be selected at the beginning
             IfNo ''as in the user does not want to make a new preset
                  MsgBox ("Enter desired values") ''values would only be saved to use this one time

After this I have some functions as for opening up a file. What is next is this code:


keepHeaders = Array("Row1", "Row3", "Row5")
```

This worked in just a test, where Row1, Row3, and Row5 were values that were kept (all other values were deleted, dont need help on that). These values though would be determined by the preset chosen or entered in (if they did not want to make a new preset), so if they chose Matt2, Row1, Row3, and Row5 would be replaced with all of the values that Matt2 would be determined as.

I am not sure if I am over complicating things or even describing it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please consider to use `UserForm` instead of `MsgBox` to get users' input if there are several options.

Answer (score 0):

As @taller suggested it looks like a `UserForm` would work best here.
With this form you can select an existing preset or create a new one.

[image]

Here I've added four controls: a combo-box, two textboxes and a command button.
In the properties for each (*View > Properties Window*) I've named them:

- cmbPreset
- txtNewPreset
- txtPresetValues
- cmdOK

Next I created a table to hold the preset values.
To create a table: type in your headings, highlight them and press `Ctrl`+`T`.
[image]

Select a cell within the table and a *Table Design* tab will appear at the top of the Excel application.  Select this and rename the table to *tblPresets*.
[image]

Now to add some code to the form:

```
'This line is very important.
'It forces you to declare all variables before using them.
'Avoids many hours of debugging due to typos.
'Tools > Options > Editor Tab > Require Variable Declarations
'^ will add it to all new modules/forms/classes you create.
Option Explicit

'Using a User Defined Type makes it easier to find your variables in intellisense.
'Just type "This." and all your variables are listed.
Private Type FormVariables
    DataTable As ListObject
    PresetValues As String
End Type
Private This As FormVariables

'Property procedures allow you to create custom properties within the form.

'Allows the Main procedure to pass the table reference to the form.
Public Property Set PresetTable(TableRef As ListObject)
    Set This.DataTable = TableRef
End Property

'Allows the Main procedure to read the final preset values from the form.
'We can use the same name as the variable as the variable has to have the
'This. keyword.
Public Property Get PresetValues() As String
    PresetValues = This.PresetValues
End Property

'This will populate your combobox using the values in the data table.
'As is Public can be called from the Main procedure.
Public Sub PopulateCombo()
    'Only populate the combobox if the data table has any data.
    If Not This.DataTable.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim PresetNames As Variant
        PresetNames = This.DataTable.ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange
        Me.cmbPreset.List = PresetNames
    End If
End Sub

'This will fire when you select a value in the combobox.
Private Sub cmbPreset_Change()
    Me.txtNewPreset = Null 'Clear the New Preset textbox.
    Me.txtPresetValues = Null 'Clear the Values textbox.
    
    'Search for the preset name in the data table using the
    'FindPreset function. If a range is found (i.e. is not nothing)
    'then place the values one cell to the right into the PresetValues textbox.
    'If nothing is found (shouldn't happen with the combobox) then
    'display a message.
    Dim FoundPreset As Range
    Set FoundPreset = FindPreset(cmbPreset.Value)
    If Not FoundPreset Is Nothing Then
        Me.txtPresetValues = FoundPreset.Offset(, 1)
    Else
        MsgBox "Preset not found", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
    End If
End Sub

'This will fire when you leave the NewPreset name textbox.
Private Sub txtNewPreset_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cmbPreset.ListIndex = -1 'Clear the combobox selection.
    
    'Check the name doesn't already exist by passing it to the FindPreset function.
    'If it does tell the user and clear the value.
        If Not FindPreset(txtNewPreset) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Preset name already exists.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Me.txtNewPreset = Null
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    'Your form should have preset values in now.
    'If they're new then add them to the data table.
    'Otherwise we can just record the actual values to pass back to the calling form.
    If Me.cmbPreset.ListIndex = -1 And Me.txtNewPreset <> "" And Me.txtPresetValues <> "" Then 'New name being added.
        Dim NewEntry As ListRow
        Set NewEntry = This.DataTable.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
        NewEntry.Range = Array(Me.txtNewPreset, Me.txtPresetValues)
    End If
    This.PresetValues = Me.txtPresetValues
    
    'Hide the form so it's still loaded in memory.
    'At this point execution passes back to the Main procedure
    'and it can unload the form when it's finished with it.
    Me.Hide
End Sub

'Search the "Name" column of the data table for the preset name.
'Will return either a reference to the cell or Nothing.
Private Function FindPreset(PresetName As String) As Range
    With This.DataTable.ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange
        Dim FoundRange As Range
        Set FoundRange = .Find(PresetName, .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext)
        Set FindPreset = FoundRange
    End With
End Function
```

Next create a normal module to contain the main code in your project.
This code:

- Creates an instance of the form.
- Tells the form what table to use.
- Tells it to populate the combo-box.  This can't be done when the form initialises as it doesn't know what table to use at that point.
- Displays the form and passes execution of the code to the form.
- Once the form is hidden it takes back control of the code.
- It then asks the now hidden form for the preset values before closing it completely.
- The final part of the code just splits the values and displays them in a message box.

There's plenty more to be done - checking the values are valid for a start.  If the values aren't comma delimited it'll fall over while trying to split it up at the end.
Plenty of improvements as well - maybe a textbox for each value that's entered, but that would need creating textboxes at runtime (use WithEvents for that).

```
Public Sub Main()

    'Create an instance of the form.
    Dim frmPreset As UserForm1
    Set frmPreset = New UserForm1
    
    With frmPreset
        'Pass it the table to use, tell it to populate the combobox
        'and finally display it.
        Set .PresetTable = shtPresets.ListObjects("tblPresets")
        .PopulateCombo
        .Show
        
        'Once the form is hidden code resume here and asks
        'for the Preset values from the form.
        Dim SelectedValues As String
        SelectedValues = .PresetValues
    End With
    
    'Close the form.
    Unload frmPreset
    
    If SelectedValues <> "" Then
    
        'Put the individual values into an array.
        Dim vValues As Variant
        vValues = Split(SelectedValues, ",")
        
        'Do something with the values.
        Dim x As Long
        Dim Msg As String
        For x = LBound(vValues) To UBound(vValues)
            Msg = Msg & vValues(x) & vbCr
        Next x
        
        MsgBox Msg, vbInformation + vbOKOnly
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Further reading:
[Writing a property procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/writing-a-property-procedure)
[User-defined data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/user-defined-data-type)
[With statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement)
[Overview of Excel tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)
[ListObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.ListObject)